# Group By sets of values

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

for a report I'm trying to query events from different shifts. The shifts start on 6 am, 2 pm, and 10 pm every day, and all of the data in the table is tagged with a datetime timestamp. Previously the graveyard shift wasn't doing anything important, so a simple `group by DATE(stamp)` was sufficient, but now it's 24/7 and I need to break it down into shifts.

Can anyone explain to me how to use a single `group by` clause to combine datetime values from a range or a set of values? The difficulty is that each graveyard shift spans two calendar days.

I've considered populating a table with 24 hours and shift numbers, then outer joining it and `group by DATE(stamp), HOUR(stamp)`, but that seems hackish and possibly not even working, plus it would give 24 values for each day instead of 3, which then have to be combined in a superquery or script.

MySQL-specific is perfectly ok, that's all we ever use in the reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they are all 8-hour shifts, offset by 6 hours from starting at midnight, you turn `Stamp` into the start-of-shift time like this:

```
select
    stamp,
    adddate(date(subdate(stamp, interval 6 hour)), 
      interval ((hour(subdate(stamp, interval 6 hour))
      div 8) * 8) + 6 hour) as shift_start
from mytable;
```

This substracts 6 hours, then rounds the hour down to either 0 1 or 2 by using integer division, then expands it out again.

Here's the test code with some edge cases:

```
create table mytable (stamp datetime);
insert into mytable values ('2011-08-17 22:00:00'), ('2011-08-17 23:01:00'), 
('2011-08-18 00:02:00'), ('2011-08-18 05:59:00'), ('2011-08-18 06:00:00'),
('2011-08-18 13:59:00'), ('2011-08-18 14:00:00'), ('2011-08-18 17:59:00');
```

Output of above query:

```
+---------------------+---------------------+
| stamp               | shift_start         |
+---------------------+---------------------+
| 2011-08-17 22:00:00 | 2011-08-17 22:00:00 |
| 2011-08-17 23:01:00 | 2011-08-17 22:00:00 |
| 2011-08-18 00:02:00 | 2011-08-17 22:00:00 |
| 2011-08-18 05:59:00 | 2011-08-17 22:00:00 |
| 2011-08-18 06:00:00 | 2011-08-18 06:00:00 |
| 2011-08-18 13:59:00 | 2011-08-18 06:00:00 |
| 2011-08-18 14:00:00 | 2011-08-18 14:00:00 |
| 2011-08-18 17:59:00 | 2011-08-18 14:00:00 |
+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Comment: This looks like a great solution, and seems to work very well on my test data and it'll be very simple to get the date and shift # from that output. I'm going to integrate it into my report now. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
GROUP BY DATE(DATE_ADD(Stamp,INTERVAL -6 HOUR))
```

That should keep all your shifts on the same day

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pursue your "table with hours and shift numbers" approach. Further, I think you should consider using a [calendar table](http://web.archive.org/web/20070611150639/http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/why-should-i-consider-using-an-auxiliary-calendar-table.html) i.e. a table not just covering 24 hours but the whole past, present and future of your enterprise's expected needs. This is not hackish: rather, it is a tried and tested approach. The idea is that SQL is a declarative language designed to query data in tables so a declarative, data-driven solutions make a lot of sense.